# Is there any way to change state inside render in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

So I am working on a dice application where I have a class component for setting the number of dice and sides of each dice with up and down buttons. My problem is that each time I press up or down button to set number of sides or number of dice, an array of random numbers gets created and displays on screen. However, I want the value to display only when the roll button is clicked.

So is there a way I can change the state of displayDice to false after I have created the array in the render, so that it only becomes true when I click roll button again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move logic to `componentDidMount`. Render is to just render UI. No business logic. It will handle event and delegate to state.

**Move generate random to parent component, pass method `rollChange` from parents to child.**

// Dice component

```
class SideAndDice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { sides: 6, dice: 1, randoms: this.generateRandom() };
  }
  increaseDice() {
    this.setState({ dice: this.state.dice + 1 });
  }
  decreaseDice() {
    if (this.state.dice > 1) {
      this.setState({ dice: this.state.dice - 1 });
    }
  }
  increaseSides() {
    this.setState({ sides: this.state.sides + 1 });
  }
  decreaseSides() {
    if (this.state.sides > 2) {
      this.setState({ sides: this.state.sides - 1 });
    }
  }
  generateRandom() {
    let randoms = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.dice; i++) {
      var randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.sides + 1);
      randoms.push(randomValue);
    }
    return randoms;
  }
  onRollDice() {
    this.setState({ randoms: this.generateRandom() });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Number of Sides</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.sides}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.increaseSides.bind(this)}>Up</button>
        <button onClick={this.decreaseSides.bind(this)}>Down</button>
        <h1>Number of Dice</h1>
        <h2>{this.state.dice}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.increaseDice.bind(this)}>Up</button>
        <button onClick={this.decreaseDice.bind(this)}>Down</button>
        <CreateScores
          randoms={this.state.randoms}
          rollChange={this.rollChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class CreateScores extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onRollDice.bind(this)}>Roll</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        {this.props.randoms.map(random => (
          <Dice key={i} diceNumber={randomValue} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how? I am new to react so I do not know

Comment: Updated! both comonent code. check now ! @LuckyGrewal Read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html